# Ito formula - some doubts

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

How can one calculate stochastic differential of the following process?

$$Y_t = \exp \left(t^2+\int_0^ts \, \mathrm d W_s\right)$$

There are two approaches, which one is correct? Both?

1. $Z_t=t^2+\int_0^ts \, dW_s$ is an Ito process, so just apply Ito formula with respect to $Z_t$ to the function $f(Z_t)=e^{Z_t}$
2. Apply Ito formula with respect to $W_t$ and $t$ to the function $f(t,W_t)=e^{t^2+\int_0^ts \, dW_s}$

Here, $W_t$ is the standard Brownian motion (Wiener process). Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: In 2), your formula does not define a function $(t,W_t)\mapsto f(t,W_t)$.

Comment: I know, but my girlfriend argues that she can apply ito formula with respect to $W_t$, not $Z_t$ in order to calculate $dY_t$

Comment: Yeah, and my grandfather disagrees. Sorry but I fail to see how this is even *relevant*. Do you have anything mathematical to share on the subject?

Comment: So 1) is the only way to calculate differential of $Y_t$ using Ito formula?

Comment: Since 2) does not exist at present, indeed 1) seems to be the only remaining option.

Comment: In principle 2) could work, the only problem is that you do not have $W_t$ in your formula, instead you have the whole path $W_s$, $s\in[0,t)$. There is no Ito formula for expressions depending on paths or segments thereof of stochastic processes.